# Extra space with "on change" bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When the select menu is changed I want the rest of the options to change.  I added in the logic using show and hide in JQuery however there is still a big gap.  I am not sure how to do it because if I get rid of the div for rows or the div for the bootstrap grid system the rest of my layout gets messed up.

I uploaded the site here:
http://devsite123.x10host.com/cgi-bin/table.html

How would I get rid of the extra space in the form when onchange or onclick some textboxes?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
  <h3> Database Details</h3>
  <select id="database" class="form-control" name="database" onchange="database_details()">
<option value="oracle" selected="selected"><b>Oracle</b></option>
<option value="mssql"><b>Sql Server</b></option>
<option value="teraData"><b>TeraData</b></option>
<option value="epic"><b>Generic ODBC(Chronicles)</b></option>
 </select>
<br>
  <div id="dns">
 <label for="db_dns">DB DNS Name *</label>
 <input type="text" id="dnsText" name="url" class="form-control" required>
 </div>

 <div id="dbName">
<label for="dbName">Database Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="dbText" name="dbName" class="form-control">
 </div>
```

Comment: Post the specific block of code that you'd like feedback on.

Comment: The elements that you show/hide are in different `row`s in your HTML, move them into the top row.

Comment: @DavidG if I move them all to the top row then the right side of the form is messed up.

Comment: It will be fine if you don't put them in side their own rows.

Comment: The row the select element is in has 2 columns. The right column has more options so it will make the row height larger which causes the gap.

Comment: so put the dns and dbName divs in there own rows?

Comment: Could put the DB Details in a row and then the TDE Refresh Option in a row under the DB Details

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's the padding you mean.
Make a css-class or put a style property with less of a padding than bootstrap default.
i.e

```
.padding-5
{
 padding:5px;
}
```

And then put this class on your elements.
Example:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control padding-5">
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having three separate divs on top of each other, why not have them all in the same one and show/hide the actual fields and labels by ID rather than the div itself?

You'll need to shift everything on the left side of the form up though, as the rows underneath won't move up on their own when they're tied to the right hand side. Leave just one empty div 'slot' and then use JavaScript to show/hide what you want using CSS classes on the fields and labels:

`document.getElementById("dbname1").setAttribute("style","display:none;");`

And when you want it to show:

`document.getElementById("dbname1").setAttribute("style","display:block;");`

You'll need to give an ID to your labels though or it won't apply to them.